# Can't get images and captions to float properly in HTML/CSS/Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am very much a newbie when it comes to building a website, and I am struggling with trying to make images with captions float properly to the left or right on my page. I simply can't make progress, because even if the image technically floats on the right of the text, it squeezes the paragraph of text to the left side of the page. Sometimes the captions also just don't want to go underneath the images like I want them to. Here's the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title> </title>
<style>
body {
    background-image:url("example");
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-size:100%;
    background-position-y:bottom;
}
figcaption {
    font-style: italic;
    font-size:small;
    padding: 2px;
}
h1 {
    text-align:center;
}
.left {
    float:inline-start;
}
.middle {
    text-align:center;
}
.right {
    float:right;
}
.center {
    display:block;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    border-style:solid;
}
img {
    border-style:solid;
    width:35%;
    height:35%;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Header</h1>
<figure class="middle">
    <img class="center" src="example1">
    <figcaption>Example</figcaption>
</figure>
<p>...</p>
<p>...</p>
<p>
    <figure class="right">
        <img src="example2">
        <figcaption>Example 2</figcaption>
    </figure>
...</p>
<p>
    <figure class="left">
        <img src="example3">
        <figcaption>Example 3</figcaption>
    </figure>    
...</p>
<p>
    <figure class="right">
        <img src="example4">
        <figcaption>Example 4</figcaption>
    </figure>
...</p>
<p>
    <figure class="left">
        <img src="example5"">
        <figcaption>Eample 5</figcaption>
    </figure>    
...</p>
<p>...</p>
<figure class="middle">
    <img src="example6">
    <figcaption>Example 6</figcaption>
</figure>
</body>
</html>
```

Edited to show what I'm going for and what I have instead.
[Example 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QkOHR.jpg)
[Example 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mlulK.png)

Comment: Are the dots is what you want to be in the middle?

Comment: The ellipses are meant to be paragraphs of text.

Comment: It's really hard to understand what's exactly is happening and what exactly you want without actual text. Can you add some text which will shows us exactly what you want/don't want.

Comment: Which one is the aim? example 1 or example 2?

Comment: Example 1 is what I'm going for.

Answer (score 0):

*is this what yo are trying to do?*
I think float is not what you need. Float is designed to make text wrap around it so the

tag will naturally squeeze away from it.

Here I used Flex and achived this:

```css
body {
  background-image: url("example");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 100%;
  background-position-y: bottom;
}

figcaption {
  font-style: italic;
  font-size: small;
  padding: 2px;
}

h1 {
  text-align: center;
}

.left {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-start;
}

.middle {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.right {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-end;
}

.center {
  display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  border-style: solid;
}

img {
  border-style: solid;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>
  <h1>Header</h1>
  <div class="middle">
    <figure>
      <img class="center" src="example1">
      <figcaption>Example</figcaption>
    </figure>
  </div>

  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Cras adipiscing enim eu turpis egestas pretium aenean pharetra. Aliquam sem fringilla ut morbi tincidunt augue. Velit dignissim
    sodales ut eu sem integer vitae. </p>
  <p>Laoreet sit amet cursus sit amet dictum sit. Morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames. Gravida quis blandit turpis cursus. Lectus urna duis convallis convallis. Massa vitae tortor condimentum lacinia quis vel eros. Maecenas accumsan lacus
    vel facilisis volutpat est velit egestas dui....</p>
  <div class="right">
    <figure>
      <img src="example2">
      <figcaption>Example 2</figcaption>
    </figure>
  </div>
  <p>
    Laoreet sit amet cursus sit amet dictum sit. Morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames. Gravida quis blandit turpis cursus. Lectus urna duis convallis convallis. Massa vitae tortor condimentum lacinia quis vel eros. Maecenas accumsan lacus
    vel facilisis volutpat est velit egestas dui.
  </p>
  <div class="left">
    <figure>
      <img src="example3">
      <figcaption>Example 3</figcaption>
    </figure>
  </div>
  <p>


    Laoreet sit amet cursus sit amet dictum sit. Morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames. Gravida quis blandit turpis cursus. Lectus urna duis convallis convallis. Massa vitae tortor condimentum lacinia quis vel eros. Maecenas accumsan lacus
    vel facilisis volutpat est velit egestas dui.

  </p>
  <div class="right">
    <figure>
      <img src="example4">
      <figcaption>Example 4</figcaption>
    </figure>
  </div>
  <p>

    Laoreet sit amet cursus sit amet dictum sit. Morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames. Gravida quis blandit turpis cursus. Lectus urna duis convallis convallis. Massa vitae tortor condimentum lacinia quis vel eros. Maecenas accumsan lacus
    vel facilisis volutpat est velit egestas dui.</p>
  <div class="left">
    <figure>
      <img src="example5">
      <figcaption>Eample 5</figcaption>
    </figure>
  </div>
  <p>

    Laoreet sit amet cursus sit amet dictum sit. Morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames. Gravida quis blandit turpis cursus. Lectus urna duis convallis convallis. Massa vitae tortor condimentum lacinia quis vel eros. Maecenas accumsan lacus
    vel facilisis volutpat est velit egestas dui.</p>
  <p>Laoreet sit amet cursus sit amet dictum sit. Morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames. Gravida quis blandit turpis cursus. Lectus urna duis convallis convallis. Massa vitae tortor condimentum lacinia quis vel eros. Maecenas accumsan lacus
    vel facilisis volutpat est velit egestas dui.</p>
  <div class="middle">
    <figure>
      <img src="example6">
      <figcaption>Example 6</figcaption>
    </figure>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: I've edited my post to show what I'm trying to do versus what I'm actually getting.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure of exactly what you want but is this close to it?

```
<style>
body {
    background-image:url("example");
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-size:100%;
    background-position-y:bottom;
}
figcaption {
    font-style: italic;
    font-size:small;
    padding: 2px;
}
h1 {
    text-align:center;
}
.left {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row-reverse;
    align-items: center;
}
.middle {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}
.right {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    align-items: center;
    
}
.center {
    display:block;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    border-style:solid;
}
img {
    border-style:solid;
    width:35%;
    height:35%;
}
</style>

<body>
<h1>Header</h1>
<figure class="middle">
    <img class="center" src="example1">
    <figcaption>Example</figcaption>
</figure>
  <p>Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum</p>
<p>Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum</p>
<p>Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum
    <figure class="right">
        <img src="example2">
        <figcaption>Example 2</figcaption>
    </figure>
Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum</p>
<p>Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum
    <figure class="left">
        <img src="example3">
        <figcaption>Example 3</figcaption>
    </figure>    
Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum</p>

<p>Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum
    <figure class="right">
        <img src="example4">
        <figcaption>Example 4</figcaption>
    </figure>
Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum</p>
<p>
    <figure class="left">
        <img src="example5">
        <figcaption>Eample 5</figcaption>
    </figure>    
Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum</p></p>
<p>Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum</p></p>
<figure class="middle">
    <img src="example6">
    <figcaption>Example 6</figcaption>
</figure>
</body>
```

Comment: I've edited my post to show what I'm trying to do versus what I'm actually getting.

Comment: try this https://codepen.io/jfirestorm44/pen/rNjRqVb?editors=1100

Comment: It's looking better than before, but now I am having issues with resizing the images. They're either too small, or they get too large and make the page impossible to read. And for whatever reason, the top image is not exactly centered in the page.

Comment: try it again. I made it a tad more responsive. Change image size here - ```.float_right {
  float: right;
  width: 30%;
  height: 30%;
}```

Comment: I'm afraid it still has the same problems.

Comment: I guess I'm confused then. I think it represents the image you posted above. I've looked at it from both a pc and iphone and the words wrap the images just like the picture you provided. The images can be resized just fine and the words flow right around them. Maybe you should post updated code or some pics of what you problem is.

Comment: Are you checking my Codepen or the code posted above? the Codepen is what I am updating. I haven't updated the code here on Stack.

Comment: Thank you for bearing with me. I think I can take things from here on out.